# Table Showing even in modal but the paragraph doesnt show

Tags: php

This is my code for my modal. im having a problem on my table because it is still showing. but when its only the paragraph tag, the words inside there are not showing. i already tried putting the table inside the p tag but still showing . what could i possibly do?

```
<!-- Modal for CONFIRM-->
       <div class="modal fade" id="ModalConfirm<?php echo $id;?>" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Are you sure you want to confirm request?<?php echo $id?> </p>
                <?php
                $modalquery="select * from tbl_informant,tbl_missing_person,tbl_contact_person
                             where concat(reported_id=mp_id && mp_id=cp_id) && informant_id=".$id;
                $modalresult=mysql_query($modalquery);
                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($modalresult)) {
              ?>
                    <form method="POST" action=""> 
                <table border=1 width="120%" style="margin-left: 60px;">
                    <tr >
                        <td colspan="3" height="40px"> 
                            <center>
                                <b>INFORMANTS INFORMATION</b>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Informants Name</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row['informant_fname'].' '.$row['informant_lname'];?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Address:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <?php echo $row['informants_address'];?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Contact</b>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <input type="number" name="informant_contact" placeholder="Enter Your Number"></input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="email" name="informant_email" placeholder="Enter Your Email"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><br><br>
                <table border=1 width="120%" style="margin-left: 60px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" height="40px" >
                            <center>
                                <b>SIGHTING INFORMATION</b>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Upper Apparel</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo$row['si_upper'];?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b>Lower Apparel</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo$row['si_lower'];?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <b>Last Location Seen:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <center>
                                <textarea cols="40" rows="3" placeholder="Enter the Last Location You've seen him/her" name="si_location"></textarea>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>
                                Childs Last Action/ Doing
                            </b>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <center>
                                <textarea cols="40" rows="3" placeholder="Enter The Childs Last Activity" name="si_activity"></textarea>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" height="50px">
                            <center>
                                <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="SUBMIT"></input>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><br><br><br>
            </form>
              <?php
                }
              ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Yes</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

this is all of the code that my confirm button should have but when it has tables the yes or no button also shows outside the modal.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML. Your PHP is irrelevant to the question. We also need to see your CSS. Oh, and the `<center>` element doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: This sounds like a CSS issue that we cannot reproduce.  If you are no longer seeking support, you may remove this question.  If you would like help, please show enough information to allow us to recreate the issue.